# How can I perform a SUM calculation for unique values in a particular column in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am trying to sum the autonomy of all unique car models in Germany.

| Key | Car model | Country | Color | Autonomy (miles) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ID3 | Germany | Green | 340 |
| 2 | Polestar 2 | Sweden | Yellow | 335 |
| 3 | EQS | Germany | Blue | 450 |
| 3 | EQS | Germany | Red | 450 |

The answer should be: 340+450=790

450 should only be considered once because Key=3 is a unique identifier (Car model) even though the colour is different.

I tried doing that using INCLUDE/FIXED LOD expressions but I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Try using "Sets" on Key  or Car model, it will let you define the way you want the SUM to be

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution!

{FIXED [Autonomy] : MIN([Autonomy])}